# why does my socket goes into a infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, next.js

Frontend:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    socketRef.current = io.connect("...", { transports : ['websocket'] })
    socketRef.current.emit("online", id)

    socketRef.current.on("message", ({ name, message }) => {
        setChat([ ...chat, { name, message , system: false } ])
    })

    socketRef.current.on("online", ( userID ) => {
        setChat([ ...chat, { name: userID , message: `has logged on` , system: true } ])
    })

    socketRef.current.on("offline", ( userID ) => {
        setChat([ ...chat, { name: userID , message: `${userID} has logged off` , system: true } ])
    })

    return () => {
        socketRef.current.disconnect()
    }
},[ chat ])
```

Backend:

```js
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('message', ({ name, message , userID }) => {
    io.emit('message', { name, message , userID })
  })

  socket.on('online', ( userID ) => {
    onlineApprovers.push({ user: userID , id: socket.id })

    console.log(userID + ' is online')
    io.emit('online', userID)
  })

  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(onlineApprovers.find(a => a.id === socket.id).user + ' is offline')
    io.emit('offline', onlineApprovers.find(a => a.id === socket.id).user)
  })
})
```

a little bit of context of what my code does:
when a user goes onto my site, it gets their user id, emits the `online` socket event, and then the backend logs `userid is online`, and when they leave my site, the socket will disconnect and then it will log `userid is offline`.

Can anyone tell me why does this goes into an infinite loop? When I log on it keeps logging `123 is online` and then it logs `123 is offline` and then `123 is online` and so on. It logged that when I didn't even close my window.

/ edit /

after removing these from my code:

```js
// socketRef.current.on("online", ( userID ) => {
//  setChat([ ...chat, { name: userID , message: `has logged on` , system: true } ])
// })

// socketRef.current.on("offline", ( userID ) => {
//  setChat([ ...chat, { name: userID , message: `${userID} has logged off` , system: true } ])
// })
```

it does not end up in an infinite loop, but then my frontend can't receive the data from my backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user joins/the `chat` state changes, you're emitting an `online` event to the server,  which the server then responds to by emitting a `online` event to all connected clients, which causes the following listener to execute:

```
socketRef.current.on("online", ( userID ) => {
  setChat([ ...chat, { name: userID , message: `has logged on` , system: true } ])
})
```

as you're calling `setChat()` here and passing through a new array, this causes your react-component to re-render, which makes the use-effect function execute again. This then fires the `online` event again which causes the loop.

Instead, you can create your socket connection when your component mounts by passing `[]` as a dependency to your `useEffect()`, and use your state updater function of `setChat()` to access the most up-to-date value of `chat`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  socketRef.current = io.connect("...", { transports : ['websocket'] });
  socketRef.current.emit("online", id);

  socketRef.current.on("message", ({ name, message }) => {
    setChat(chat => [ ...chat, { name, message , system: false } ]);
  });

  socketRef.current.on("online", ( userID ) => {
    setChat(chat => [ ...chat, { name: userID , message: `has logged on` , system: true } ]);
  });

  socketRef.current.on("offline", ( userID ) => {
    setChat(chat => [ ...chat, { name: userID , message: `${userID} has logged off` , system: true } ]);
  });

  return () => {
    socketRef.current.disconnect();
  };

}, []);
```

Comment: so i don't need the `disconnect` function?

Comment: @shennytan you do, you might need to refresh your browser to see my latest edit

Comment: it still goes in a infinite loop for some reason

Comment: @shennytan hm, not sure what else it would be, make sure you save and refresh your page and ensure that you have removed `[chat]` from the dependency list so that it's using just `[]`. Also, make sure you don't have any other effects that could be emitting the "online" event.

Comment: OH i forgot to remove the `[ chat ]` part from my useEffect, thanks so much! it is not looping anymore